# Sorting a linked list upon insertion

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

While I know that there are lots of examples of sorting a linked list, they are based around abstracting the sorting to a separate function which is called after the list has been generated, and sadly that doesn't suffice for what I am trying to do. The code below is my attempt at inserting a key/word pair into a linked list in the correct position so that when all values have been inserted the list is sorted, and it works for most cases but seems to throw up an error when the first item scanned is also the first item in the list.

For example, the input of:
0 ant
7 world
3 kodak
1 best
6 the
2 is

produces the linked list:
World -> best -> is -> kodak ->the ->world

Yet if you change the input to:
7 world
0 ant
3 kodak
1 best
6 the
2 is

it produces the linked list:
ant -> best->is->kodak->the->world

Here's the offending code:

```
        while(fscanf(fp,"%d %s\n", &traversor->key, traversor->word) == 2){


            newnode =  malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
            newnode->key = traversor->key;
            strcpy(newnode->word, traversor->word);

            traversor = dict_head;

            while(traversor->next!= tailnode){

                if(traversor->next->key > newnode->key){break;}

                traversor = traversor->next;
            }
            printf("Traversor is sitting on %s\n", traversor->word);
            newnode->next = traversor->next;
            traversor->next = newnode;
            traversor = dict_head;
            for(x = 0; x < list_size; x++)
            {
                printf("%d %s %d ->", traversor, traversor->word, traversor->key);
                traversor = traversor->next;
            }
            printf("%d %s %d",traversor->next, traversor->next->word, traversor->next->key);

            printf("\n");
            list_size++;
        }
```

Any insight that can be offered would be greatly appreciated, I am still getting to grips with pointers so it is highly likely that it is a really basic error, but sadly after many hours of looking at it I haven't been able to figure out what it is.

Edit:

```
struct node_t{
    int key;
    char word[WORDLEN];
    struct node_t *next;
};
```

Here is the node struct.

Comment: How did you know that you reach to your tailnode???

Comment: I have taken out a lot of the debugging printfs to make it easier to read, but if you add in a print while loop that starts at the head of the list and traverses through, when you get to the end the last node was pointing to the tail node (and was doing so in both cases mentioned above).

Comment: My question is why you are not comparing a pointer to `NULL`...

Comment: Ah misunderstood you sorry. I changed it to while(traversor->next != NULL) and it gives the same output.

Comment: Actually it is,  because by resetting the traversor back to the head of the list after each scan through you are able to generate more than 2 items. Admittedly I have neglected to include the lines where I malloc traversor and dict_head, but I can guarantee you that this is the code used to generate the output.

Comment: @Spacepotato :  Agreed vis. the linkage, but I still do not believe this is the real code. However, I'll reverse my downvote if you edit in what `printf("Traversor is sitting on %s\n", traversor->word)` does on the first insertion (and be honest).

Comment: On the first insertion it will be sitting on dict_head which doesn't have a word assigned to it (just a key of 0) so it prints out a junk string.

Comment: Ah ;) Well, I can't change my vote unless you edit, and I would suggest that details like this, although you may consider them irrelevant, are not irrelevant to understanding the problem. Eg, evidently you've allocated the head of an empty list, which is not necessarily wrong, but it is not the most common approach either.  The proper (as in, most helpful to your readers) way to ask a programming question (which will be the most helpful to you in the end) is to *reduce the problem to something that can be easily reproduced*.

Comment: Which means in part: code and output which match *in all details*. That may require additional work on your part.  I'll also suggest in a hopefully friendly way that Stack Exchange is not a great place to *learn* programming, although it may be a great place to ask specific questions.  For C: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/forum.php Bring a tough skin ;)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up goldilocks, wasnt aware that it was unconvential to have the head node as a node containing only a pointer I just assumed that this would simplify passing the list into functions.  And I wholeheartedly agree but I thought it appropriate to ask here as the question is more bug focused than concept focused :)

Comment: Probably the main reason that's not the normative method is because it's just as easy to, e.g., check if `head == NULL` or `head == tail` as it is to check if `head->next == NULL` or `head->next == tail`.  Usually, you'd have a "node" struct type and a "list" struct type (containing a head node pointer), so that you can pass the list around and potentially reassign the head pointer within it.

Comment: Good you took my advice, but indicate when you crosspost : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/158865-sorting-linked-list-upon-node-insertion.html

Answer (score 1):

My solution...

First change your `While` loop

```
while(traversor->next!= NULL)
{
    if(traversor->next->key > newnode->key)
    {
         break;
    }
    traversor = traversor->next;
}
```

Second : For the very first time you need to check that if your list is `empty` or not.

```
if(dict_head == NULL)
{
     dict_head = newnode;
     dict_head->next = NULL;
}
```

then your else part

```
else
{
    newnode->next = traversor->next;
    traversor->next = newnode;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 Hopefully this jibes with whatever other material the OP is consulting.

Comment: @goldilocks...If you know what is the problem why didn`t you answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no place where you are assigning to `dict_head`, and that seems to be a bug. I am guessing it starts as something else that will need to be changed once the very first node is inserted.

You will probably need a special `if` to test if you are currently inserting the very first node.